# Factory Method Pattern vs inheritance

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns, factory

What is the point in using this pattern?
Considering this article it's just senseless: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method

Why not to use simple inheritance?
Here's a little comparison:
https://codesandbox.io/s/factory-method-pattern-vs-good-old-inheritance-opovv?file=/src/inheritance.ts

Comment: Inheritance goes from simple to complex in a heartbeat. Sites that explain with diagrams don't help me at all. Not saying they're bad, but seeing examples in code helps sometimes. A good principle to read about is "favor composition over inheritance." This is a bit dated, but here's a factory pattern blog post: http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/02/23/abstract-factory-pattern.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one versus the other; Factory Method uses polymorphism, via inheritance, to defer object creation to subclasses.

Don't confuse patterns as being greater than their constituents. Patterns are simply names for common use cases of software design, because anything important deserves a name.

Comment: There is versus. Method "class A extends B" also uses "polymorphism, via inheritance, to defer object creation to subclasses".

Comment: No, you're just confused.